# CustomIOSAlertView disappears in the upper opening of the keyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, ios9

I am using a `CustomIOSAlertView alertView * = [ [ CustomIOSAlertView alloc ] init ];` in my application . The problem is that when I run my app on ios 8 or 9 I will write in a text field of `CustomIOSAlertView` , the opening at the top of the keyboard disappears .

Comment: Not getting your issue exactly

Comment: even from the image below? high glimpse the CustomIOSAlertView. When I try to write in CustomIOSAlertView goes high .